# Convert char into KeyEvent on Android

Tags: java, android, keyevent, keycode

I cannot manage to get a character recognized by the `KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyEvent)` function.
I've tried:

```
KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(Character.getNumericValue('5')); // Output: KEYCODE_CALL
KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue('5')))); // Output: KEYCODE_CALL
```

The correct output will be used to compare with the `keyCode` variable in the function I'm working on.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's working as expected.  5 is KEYCODE_CALL.  The number 5 is KEYCODE_5, which has a numeric value of 12.

I'm not sure why you're using KEYCODE constants at all though.  There's almost certainly better ways to do it, especially since almost no keyboards send KEYCODE events.

Comment: My goal is to detect if a key that was pressed is less than this value. I need to detect it from a char because this value is actually stored in a separate XML file, and I want to modify the value from that file.

Comment: Well, you're unlikely to actually get KeyEvents when a user presses keys on the softkeyboard, so you may need to rethink this approach.  KeyEvents are only assured for physical buttons.

Comment: Okay. Do you have a suggestion?